# How do I force a date/time format for traffic captured with tshark using "-T fields"?

Tags: logstash, date, formatting, tshark

I'm capturing traffic with tshark into a CSV file using "-T fields", but whatever I try I can't get a nice ISO date or even changing the timezone to UTC.

The command I'm using is

```
tshark.exe -i 2 -c 1 -T fields -e frame.time
```

This gives me

```
Capturing on 'Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller' 
May 20, 2016 13:46:03.565211000 Hora oficial do Brasil
```

I've tried adding

- -o column.format:"Time,%Yut"
- -t ad
- -t ud

Not even "-t d" and "-t r" will change the format.

I'm running tshark in a Windows box with the OS installed in Portuguese (pt-BR) and even if I change the date language between English and Portuguese all I get is this strange mix of languages between the date and the timezone.

It seems that tshark under Windows ignores all the options to format dates.

I don't really need to have an ISO date, but I need one that can be parsed with the date{} filter in logstash. It could almost parse the one I'm getting, but it can't handle the "Hora oficial do Brasil" and I can't shake it off the time.frame text.

Update: I've found that on Ubuntu also the "-t" parameter has no effect. There, tshark prints the date/time part using the same format as in Windows, but it never prints a timezone name/offset/id. Even if it is a bug, the Unix behaviour would fix my problem...

Comment: Don't know anything about what logstash will accept, or what exactly you're trying to capture...but you might try "windump" which is tcpdump for windows.  It has some output options, maybe you can get it to do what you need.

Comment: I don't have any issues with what I'm trying to capture, except for the frame.time part. If I can get it with a time zone that can be parsed (offset or id, instead of the name), it would be enough. I'm using tshark because I  want to use the Wireshark fields, much easier to work with than tcpdump.

Comment: I didn't think you had an issue with what tshark did give you, i was suggesting a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment, it is not possible to do what I wanted.

There is a enhancement request posted at Wireshark Bug Database for this feature.

[#10220 - add ISO 8601 date format option to tshark -T fields (FT_ABSOLUTE_TIME type fields)](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10220)